# Docker stack deploy command error running compose yml file docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml, docker-swarm

```
[root@d1 docker]# docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml getstartedlab
yaml: line 12: did not find expected key
```

> Here is the docker yml file I am using please see the docker-compose.yml file below listed

```html
version: "3"
services:
   web:
      image: pragneshpanchal/httpdsrv
      deploy:
        replicas: 5
        resources:
           limits:
              cpus: "0.1"
              memory: 50M
           restart_policy:
              condition:on-failure
          ports:
             - "4000:80"
          networks:
              - webnet
        networks:
          webnet:
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a space between `condition:` and `on-failure`. Please add a space and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Did you put your Yaml through a yaml validator?

It's really sensitive to the indentation, so if you put one too many space at some place you can have some strange behavior even with something valid.

I tried to put you file through this validator (http://www.yamllint.com/) and it came false when copy/pasted in it. Try to respect a 2 spaces when working on a child item, like this:

```
services:
  web:
    image: pragneshpanchal/httpdsrv
```

For the moment I can see multiple type of spacing and this will always get you errors. Like in ports and the first network call.

For the second network call, it should be at the same level as services.

And lastly, as stated in Mark answer's there is a missing space in your restart condition.